# Using Javascript object in seperate file

Tags: javascript, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm using Nativescript-vue. I'm trying to put some logic in my app, that doesn't show any html or anything, its just a library that does calculations. I can't figure out how to just use it, i keep getting error messages.

Here is what I've tried.

rifle.js

```
 export function Rifle () { // no function name
   this.firstName = "hi";
  }
```

also tried this and others:

```
const observableModule = require("tns-core-modules/data/observable");


function Rifle () { // no function name
   const myRifle = observableModule.fromObject({
        firstName:"hello"
   })

   return myRifle;
  }

  module.exports = Rifle;
```

then in my App.js file, i import it.

```
import {Rifle} from "./ballisticlibrary/rifle";
```

I've also tried to use Require instead.

I then try to use it in a vue method, invoked on button tap.

```
  GetRifle()
  {
     // return "hi";
   this.msg= this.Rifle.firstName;

  }
```

Keeps throwing an error of :

```
Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined"
System.err: An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
System.err: Calling js method onClick failed
System.err: TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined
```

Comment: I have never used vue but i would expect the exported Rifle value to be a function or a class. That would suggest that you need to first create an instance of that class before using it. Also, i think that you cant access the imported classes using "this".
you can try . const rifle = new Rifle();  this.msg = rifle.firstName;

Comment: @RainerPlumer this worked, export function Rifle () { // no function name
    this.firstName=  "hi";
    function GetHelp (){
        return "Help"
    }
  }  

Do you know why my function GetHelp wouldn't work though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- moved a comment into an answer for better formatting *

I have never used vue but I would expect the exported Rifle value to be a function or a class. That would suggest that you need to first create an instance of that class before using it. 
Also, I think that you cant access the imported classes using "this". you can try.

```
// your rifle class
export function Rifle () {
    this.name = "AK-47";
    this.damage = 5;
    this.fire = () => {
        console.log('Bang bang, '+ this.damage + ' damage done by ' + this.name);
    }
}

// then import your rifle and instantiate it

const ak = new Rifle();
ak.fire();

// logs out Bang bang, 5 damage done by AK-47
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've been struggling to get this to work like this for awhile, and this did it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is `this.firstName`. Read [this](https://medium.com/better-programming/understanding-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-cb76d4c7c5e8) to better understand how to use `this` in js.